# Parsing brainf*ck code to tree in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, brainfuck

I am trying to write an optimizing brainfuck compiler in Rust. Currently it stores tokens in a flat vector, which works, but I am having trouble changing it to use a syntax tree:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Token {
    Output,
    Input,
    Loop(Vec<Token>),
    Move(i32),
    Add(i32, i32),
    LoadOut(i32, i32),
}
use Token::*;

pub fn parse(code: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut alltokens = Vec::new();
    let mut tokens = &mut alltokens;
    let mut tokvecs: Vec<&mut Vec<Token>> = Vec::new();
    for i in code.chars() {
        match i {
            '+' => tokens.push(Add(0, 1)),
            '-' => tokens.push(Add(0, -1)),
            '>' => tokens.push(Move(1)),
            '<' => tokens.push(Move(-1)),
            '[' => {
                tokens.push(Loop(Vec::new()));
                tokvecs.push(&mut tokens);
                if let &mut Loop(mut newtokens) = tokens.last_mut().unwrap() {
                    tokens = &mut newtokens;
                }
            },
            ']' => {
                tokens = tokvecs.pop().unwrap();
            },
            ',' => tokens.push(Input),
            '.' => {
                tokens.push(LoadOut(0, 0));
                tokens.push(Output);
            }
            _ => (),
        };
    }

    alltokens
}
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to handle the `[` command. The current implementation in the code is one of several I have tried, all of which have failed. I think it may require use of Rust's `Box`, but I can't quite understand how that is used.

The branch handling the `[` command is probably completely wrong, but I'm not sure how it should be done. It pushes a `Loop` (a variant of the `Token` enum) containing a vector to the `tokens` vector. The problem is to then get a mutable borrow of the vector in that `Loop`, which the `if let` statement is supposed to do.

The code fails to compile since `newtokens` does not outlive the end of the `if let` block. Is it possible to get a mutable reference to the vector inside `Loop`, and set `tokens` to it? If not, what could be done instead?

Comment: @ljedrz Fixed that. I must have accidentally deleted the opening brace fixing the indentation before posting.

Comment: Why do you need 3 variables for tokens? This seems unnecessarily complicated; take `tokens` - it's just a mutable reference to `alltokens`. Why not just use `&mut alltokens` when it's needed?

Comment: @ljedrz I'd be happy to hear of a simpler way. `alltokens` is the main vector of tokens. The parser adds tokens to that vector, but once it gets to a loop, it adds a `Loop` token that contains a vector of tokens, which is based on the contents of that loop. So I used `tokens` to point to the vector of the current level of the tree, and `tokvecs` to store the levels above so it can go up the tree when it reaches the end of a loop (the `]` command).

Comment: **What problem do you want solved?** Right now, the code has the error ``expected type `&mut Token`, found type `Token```. Are you asking what that means? I'm sure there's a question dealing with that. [edit] your question to actually *ask* a question. Be sure not to ask an overly broad question.

Comment: @Shepmaster That specific error is not really the issue; I'm fairly sure by now that an `if let` statement is not the right way to implement it; it's one of several things I've tried. I'll try to update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to improve the question. Hopefully that is better. It is somewhat difficult to be specific, since I think I'm doing this the wrong way. If it was just a matter of getting the `if let` to typecheck, I would have included only a few lines of code and addressed the error more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten the code to work by making it a recursive function:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Token {
    Output,
    Input,
    Loop(Vec<Token>),
    Move(i32),
    Add(i32, i32),
    LoadOut(i32, i32),
}
use Token::*;

pub fn parse(code: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    _parse(&mut code.chars())
}

fn _parse(chars: &mut std::str::Chars) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    while let Some(i) = chars.next() {
        match i {
            '+' => tokens.push(Add(0, 1)),
            '-' => tokens.push(Add(0, -1)),
            '>' => tokens.push(Move(1)),
            '<' => tokens.push(Move(-1)),
            '[' => tokens.push(Loop(_parse(chars))),
            ']' => { break; }
            ',' => tokens.push(Input),
            '.' => {
                tokens.push(LoadOut(0, 0));
                tokens.push(Output);
            }
            _ => (),
        };
    }

    tokens
}
```

It seems to work, and is reasonably simple and elegant (I'd still be interested to see a solution that doesn't use recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, last time I was pretty close; it looks like I missed the `ref` keyword:

`if let &mut Loop(ref mut newtokens) = (&mut tokens).last_mut().unwrap()`

I missed it since there were other borrow checker errors everywhere. I decided to simplify your code to tackle them:

```
pub fn parse(code: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    for i in code.chars() {
        match i {
            '+' => tokens.push(Add(0, 1)),
            '-' => tokens.push(Add(0, -1)),
            '>' => tokens.push(Move(1)),
            '<' => tokens.push(Move(-1)),
            '[' => {
                tokens.push(Loop(Vec::new()));
                if let &mut Loop(ref mut newtokens) = (&mut tokens).last_mut().unwrap() {
                    let bracket_tokens: &mut Vec<Token> = newtokens;
                }
            },
            ']' => {
                ()
            },
            ',' => tokens.push(Input),
            '.' => {
                tokens.push(LoadOut(0, 0));
                tokens.push(Output);
            }
            _ => unreachable!(),
        };
    }

    tokens
}
```

I merged all of the token variables (you don't really need them) and changed `tokens = &mut newtokens;` to `let bracket_tokens: &mut Vec<Token> = newtokens;` (I think this was more or less your intention). This allows you to manipulate the `Vec`tor inside the `Loop`.

However, this code still has issues and won't parse brainf*ck's loops; I wanted to make it work, but it required a significant change of approach. You are welcome to try to expand this variant further but it might be a painful experience, especially if you are not too familiar with the borrow checker's rules yet.

I suggest looking at brainf*ck interpreters implementations (e.g. [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92843/rust-brainfuck-interpreter)) by other people (though not too old, as Rust's syntax has changed before 1.0 went live) to get an idea how this can be done.

Comment: `tokens` isn't superfluous, because its value changes (it refers to the current branch in the tree, which initially is `alltokens` but inside the `if let` is changed to the new branch). This also doesn't fix the problem, but that is probably my fault for not being clear enough. I now get "`newtokens` does not live long enough" on the line `tokens = &mut newtokens;`. So I need a reference that I can set a variable to and use throughout the function. I'm guessing this isn't possible, but I don't know what the alternative would be.

Comment: I don't think getting rid of those variables really works. The problem is that after the `[` command, the following commands should not be added to the original `Vec`, but to the new `Vec` contained in the `Loop`. The "Syntactic Analysis" section of [this article](http://blog.justinpoliey.com/transpiling-languages-an-intro-with-brainfuck.html) contains a python implementation of something similar to my function, which does use essentially the same 3 variable. In comparing the code in that article to mine, `ast=alltokens`, `stack=tokvecs`, and `node=tokens`.

Comment: You can add tokens after the bracket exactly to the vector inside Loop - try pushing any Token to bracket_tokens and print the results of parsing some brainf*ck.